# How to generate oneOf using springdoc from a Kotlin sealed class

Tags: kotlin, swagger, openapi, springdoc

I have an existing Kotlin model which is a sealed class

```kotlin
sealed class AnyShape(val type: ShapeType) {
    enum class ShapeType { Square,  Circle }
    
    data class Square(val size: Float) : AnyShape(ShapeType.Square)
    data class Circle(val radius: Float) : AnyShape(ShapeType.Circle)
}
```

My existing, manually written OpenAPI spec defines this model using the `oneOf` to express the polymorphism:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    AnyShape:
      discriminator:
        propertyName: type
      oneOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Square'
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Circle'
    Circle:
      required:
      - radius
      - type
      type: object
      properties:
        radius:
          type: number
          format: float
    Square:
      required:
      - size
      - type
      type: object
      properties:
        size:
          type: number
          format: float
```

Now, instead of maintaining the yaml spec manually, I'd like to generate it from the Kotlin code using [springdoc-openapi](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi) so I annotated my `AnyShape` as follows:

```kotlin
@Schema(
    oneOf = [AnyShape.Square::class, AnyShape.Circle::class],
    discriminatorProperty = "type"
)
sealed class AnyShape {
    @Schema(enumAsRef = true)
    enum class ShapeType { Square, Circle }

    data class Square(val size: Float) : AnyShape() {
        val type = ShapeType.Square
    }

    data class Circle(val radius: Float) : AnyShape() {
        val type = ShapeType.Circle
    }
}
```

However the generated yaml spec is not what I'd expect because the main `AnyShape` is of type `object` but I'd like to be just the `oneOf` type (as above)

```yaml
omponents:
  schemas:
    AnyShape:
      type: object  # <<<< THIS
      discriminator:
        propertyName: type
      oneOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Square'
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Circle'
    Circle:
      required:
      - radius
      - type
      type: object
      properties:
        radius:
          type: number
          format: float
        type:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ShapeType'
    ShapeType:
      type: string
      enum:
      - Square
      - Circle
    Square:
      required:
      - size
      - type
      type: object
      properties:
        size:
          type: number
          format: float
        type:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ShapeType'
```

How could I achieve that the generated yaml is the same as the one I initially wrote manually (1st example)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for.. as the spec looks correct. There is still the parent type and child types. OneOf is a property of a supertype/type not a component or API, so where would it go without the supertype generating as its own object? Do you see where I'm confused about your question?

Comment: hey, I modified slightly my original question code. The sealed class now does not have any properties and I'd expect it to generate a pure `oneOf` yaml schema. I ended up opening an issue in swagger-core https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/4156